# how to make the submit button wait until checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, html

How to make the submit button go the link destination , but first the checkbox must be checked ?

My issue is whenever I click on Pay: it doesn't wait the ckeckbox to be checked

```js
function checkForm(form) {

  if (!form.terms.checked) {
    alert("Please indicate that you accept the Terms and Conditions");
    form.terms.focus();
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
const pay = document.getElementById("submitBtn");
pay.addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  window.location.href = "google.com"
}
```

```html
<form class="n-chk" style="margin-bottom:1em ;text-align:center;">
  <label class="new-control new-checkbox checkbox-primary">
    <input onsubmit="return checkForm(this);" type="checkbox" required  >

    <span class="new-control-indicator"></span>
    <span class="text-dark"> I agree to the
    <a href="#" target="_blank" class="text-primary px-1" style="text-decoration: none;">Terms of Use </a> &
    <a href="#" target="_blank" class="text-primary px-1" style="text-decoration: none;">Privacy Policy </a>
    </span>
    </label>
  <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="button" autocomplete="off">
</form>
```

Comment: @mplungjan when i click on submit even the button is not checked it goes to the link

Comment: Remove ALL the script. The check is required, The browser will stop the submission. Use the form action to go to the URL you want

Answer (score 1):

1. `onsubmit="return checkForm(this);"` belongs on the form element
2. But since you made it required, just remove all JS and add the action to the form
3. Also never add event handlers to submit buttons. Add an eventListener to the submit event instead and use preventDefault

So EITHER this

```html
<form action="yourpaymentpage.php" class="n-chk" style="margin-bottom:1em ;text-align:center;">
  <label class="new-control new-checkbox checkbox-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" required  >

    <span class="new-control-indicator"></span>
    <span class="text-dark"> I agree to the
    <a href="#" target="_blank" class="text-primary px-1" style="text-decoration: none;">Terms of Use </a> &
    <a href="#" target="_blank" class="text-primary px-1" style="text-decoration: none;">Privacy Policy </a>
    </span>
    </label>
  <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="button" autocomplete="off">
</form>
```

OR (not recommended)

```js
document.getElementById("form1").addEventListener("submit",e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  location = "yourpaymentpage.php";
})
```

```html
<form id="form1" class="n-chk" style="margin-bottom:1em ;text-align:center;">
  <label class="new-control new-checkbox checkbox-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" required  >

    <span class="new-control-indicator"></span>
    <span class="text-dark"> I agree to the
    <a href="#" target="_blank" class="text-primary px-1" style="text-decoration: none;">Terms of Use </a> &
    <a href="#" target="_blank" class="text-primary px-1" style="text-decoration: none;">Privacy Policy </a>
    </span>
    </label>
  <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="button" autocomplete="off">
</form>
```